# Substr instr help needed in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, regexp-substr, instr

i am trying to fetch some text from HTML string from a table. the text are like this and i am trying to get the output

```
ID,TEXT
1,<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">ABC 123</font>
2,<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">1 ETG</font>
3,<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">Gatelys PERC</font>
4,<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">Gml TK 144</font>

ID,TEXT
1,ABC 123
2,1 ETG
3,Gatelys PERC
4,Gml TK 144
```

I have tried this but not getting right output.

```
select ID,regexp_substr(TEXT, '[^>]+',1,2) from TABLE
where TEXT is not null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML is always valid XHTML then you should use XML functions to parse the string:

```sql
SELECT id,
       XMLQUERY('*/text()' PASSING XMLTYPE(text) RETURNING CONTENT) AS text
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, text) AS
  Select 1, '<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">ABC 123</font>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select 2, '<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">1 ETG</font>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select 3, '<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">Gatelys PERC</font>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select 4, '<font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size="8" color="#000000">Gml TK 144</font>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select 5, '<font attr=">">XYZ</font>' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC 123 |
| 2 | 1 ETG |
| 3 | Gatelys PERC |
| 4 | Gml TK 144 |
| 5 | XYZ |

---

If you want to naively remove all tags using string functions then you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '<.*?>') AS text
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC 123 |
| 2 | 1 ETG |
| 3 | Gatelys PERC |
| 4 | Gml TK 144 |
| 5 | ">XYZ |

*Note, it will fail if you have attributes inside a tag that contain a `>` character.*

If you want a more comprehensive query then:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(text, q'{<([^"']+?|".*?"|'.*?')+?>}') AS text
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs the same as the XML query.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GqjADGhO)

Comment: yes, secord sql is working, actually data type was not XMLTYPE, so xml perser not needed. but '<.*?>' works.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it using `regexp_substr` :

```
select ID,regexp_substr(TEXT, '>([^<>]+)<', 1, 1, null, 1) 
from mytable
where TEXT is not null;
```

Comment: This will not give a correct value for the input `<font attr=">abc<">XYZ</font>` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qs4IO-NT)